# Why are exceptions thrown from mocks gone when using method count?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mocking, spock

I am testing some Java code using spock unit tests. In one test case I need to test if a class behaves correctly when an exception is thrown. I mocked the call to throw an exception and then I test if the method is called and if the returned result is correct.

The code I'm using is rather lengthy so I narrowed it down to this example which is a somewhat pointless test but still illustrates the problem:

```
def "test if an exception is thrown on a mock"() {
    given:
        Object o = Mock() {
            toString() >> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException("no message")}
        }
    when:
        o.toString()
    then:
        thrown(UnsupportedOperationException)
}
```

This works fine. The exception is thrown from the mock and the test runs green. However if I add a method call counter the exception is not thrown anymore. If I change the `then` block to

```
then:
    1 * o.toString()
    thrown(UnsupportedOperationException)
```

the test fails. I checked with a debugger and it turns out that `toString()` now returns null instead of throwing an exception. Why does this happen and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is well explained in spock document.
Please refer to [this section](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing)

For a quick fix, I suggest

```
def "test if an exception is thrown on a mock"() {
    given:
        Object o = Mock() {
            // Stubbing and Mock-verifying at the same time
            1 * toString() >> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException("no message")}
        }
    when:
        o.toString()
    then:
        thrown(UnsupportedOperationException)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it. As I read the documentation, it's impossible to split the declaration from the verification, right? That does make the spec less readable. I would much prefer to declare the mock in the ```given``` section and do the verification in the ```then``` section.

Comment: @pitachips the idiomatic way is to have the verification and stubbing in the `then` block.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I agree. That's how it's usually done.